# ready(function() doesn´t work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this **jquery function** to **scroll into a div coming from a link at the index**; when I execute the action (clicking on the link to go to the secondary page) and the scroll is executed, it works but not with the right 'scrollTop' measurement.

I realize that it works correctly until I reload the page. I do not know if I'm using the correct function.

```
var locationString = window.location.hash;
var headerHeight = -70;

$(document).ready(function(){
     var divLoc = $(locationString).offset();
     console.log(locationString, divLoc.top , divLoc.top + headerHeight);
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divLoc.top + headerHeight}, "slow");
 });
```

Comment: `$(locationString).offset()` is not what you think it is

Comment: Check error in console.

Comment: @Jaydp I'm not getting any error in the console

Comment: @Arvind I'm sorry, I do not understand your comment, 
could you explain me a little more??

Comment: @RachGlucio - have you got values for all console data which you printed
console.log(locationString, divLoc.top , divLoc.top + headerHeight);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common cause is the miss understanding of two event related to the page load: `$(document).ready()` (all elements of the DOM are ready to query/modify or whatever) and `$(window).load()` (all the images and related css are ready and the page will be rendered and will be fully displayed by the browser).

If you use `$(document).ready()` to apply actions that need all the page to be loaded for correctly display all the sizing, it will fail, because the images are not loaded yet so the vertical offsets (as in your case) may not be correctly computed.

So you need to use `$(window).load()` instead, so when you scroll to the element you will ensure that the page is fully rendered an all the elements will be placed as they should be.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! :) 
It was just what I needed!